# Convert array<map<string,string>> type to <string,string> in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I am facing in problem in converting a column in my dataframe to string format. The example of the dataframe is as follows:

```
-- example_code_b: string (nullable = true)
-- example_code: array (nullable = true)
[info]  |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
[info]  |    |    |-- key: string
[info]  |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I want to convert `example code` to `(string,string)` format from the current `array(map(string,string))`.

> The input is in the form of `[Map(entity -> PER), Map(entity -> PER)]` and 
>   I want the output to be in the form of `PER,PER`

Comment: is the example_code.. array of size one ?..

Comment: No, it has multiple arguments

Answer (score 1):

you can either do an UDF in DataFrame API or use Dataset-API to do it:

```
import spark.implicits._

df
  .as[Seq[Map[String,String]]]
  .map(s => s.reduce(_ ++ _))
  .toDF("example_code")
  .show()
```

Note that this does not consider the case of multiple keys, they are not "merged" but just overwritten

Comment: Hey, I him this error : `Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
[error]     .map(s => s.reduce(_ ++ _))
`

Comment: I have imported the implicits:
`import spark.implicits._
  df
    .as[Seq[Map[String,String]]]
    .map(s => s.reduce(_ ++ _))
    .toDF("ex_code")
    .show() `

Comment: This doesnt work. The input is in the form of `[Map(entity -> PER), Map(entity -> PER)]` and I want it to be in the form of  `PER,PER`

Comment: Hey Raphael, this code doesnt work. Do you have an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `explode` function on any array column, which will create separate rows for each value of array.

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("mymap" explode(col("example_code")))
```

Comment: hey, exploding prints out each input in consecutive rows, I want them to be in the same row, separated by a `,`

Comment: Mean, you want merge all the value in single Map?

Comment: Yes. This doesnt work. The input is in the form of `[Map(entity -> PER), Map(entity -> PER)]` and I want it to be in the form of  `PER,PER`